# Why is keras SGD not optimizing properly?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am developing a reinforcement learning agent. I already have the structure and algorithm figured out. Currently my aim is to improve the stability of the learning process. I am using keras for the ML part, and had great result with adam optimizer. Here is a graph of the process in 100 runs (good result but really unstable learning process).[image: Adam optimizer run]
I already said i want to improve stability, so I tried switching the optimizer to SGD, here is the result (really confusing to me, because it seems to be getting steadily worse).
[image: SGD optimizer run]
The only difference between one run and the other is the optimizer. Any ideas what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information but this intuition can explain what you are seeing.

While Adam has an adaptive step size, SGD doesn't. This means that SGD may start bouncing in the ravine when the step size is too big.

[image]

The picture belongs to the following article https://blog.paperspace.com/intro-to-optimization-momentum-rmsprop-adam/

If the step size is kept constant, the optimizer will keep bouncing between "walls". Adam instead is able to reduce step size resulting in better results.

If you try reducing the step size in SGD you will probably get better results, however, the number of required iterations will increase.

Comment: Why would the optimization get worse due to this? Shouldn't it just bounce around at some sub-optimal values instead?

Comment: I undestand what you suggest, but it seems that if that were the case, I would be getting a slow, but actual improvement, instead what I am experiencing is a constant decrease in the model accuracy. Anyway, I will try to reduce de step size in the SGD somehow and observe the result.